# Node Js - Mongo DB - Update Many

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is an example database I have in mongodb.

```
[
 {name: "Tommy", age: 12, _id: 12345 },
 {name: "Pat", age: 22, _id: 54321 },
 {name: "Bridie", age: 64, _id: 98765 }
]
```

How do I update the age of Pat to be 50 and the age of Tommy to be 20 in a single query using updateMany?

Im currently updating them individually in a for loop using this method.

```
const peopleToBeUpdated = [
    { name: "Pat", age: 50 },
    { name: "Tommy", age: 20 }
]

for (const person of peopleToBeUpdated) {
    try {

        await peopleSchema.updateOne({ name: person.name }, { $set: { age: person.age  }})
   
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks..

Comment: You can use the Updates with Aggregation Pipeline feature.

Comment: Did you have a look at Bulk updates? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#mongodb-method-db.collection.bulkWrite

Comment: Yeah, I've just decided to go with a map rather than a for loop, seems to be working fine..